# App don`t start from index.jsp as it declared in web.xml <welcome-file-list> after deploy on GCloud

Tags: google-app-engine

**Problem you have encountered:**
 - after deploy app to appengine on gcloud with gradle default web page is index.html. BUT in web.xml  declared:
    `<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>`

in local environment it start from index.jsp as I expected and declared, but after deploy is not

**What you expected to happen:**
 - app start from index.jsp page. as it declared

I deploy to appEngine with Gradle https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I followed that an after adding this to the `web.xml` file:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">

    <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>
```

My app started with the `index.jsp` file even when there was the `index.html` file too.

I also share with you the section of App Engine of my `build.gradle` file:

```
appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        projectId = System.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
        version = 'GCLOUD_CONFIG'
    }
}
```

Comment: my **web.xml** : 
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javae`e/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>```

Comment: my file is the same, what could be wrong?
how to check if the start page configuration is specified correctly in the WAR file ?

Comment: You can use [Cloud Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger). In addition, you can deploy to a new version instead to the same version name